# Using nHibernate and QueryOver how can I join 3 tables

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, queryover

**BACKGROUND:**
Given 3 tables

```
results contains 2 columns vId and pId  
vTable contains 2 columns vId and data  
pTable contains 2 columns pId and data
```

I want to accomplish this sort of SQL query using QueryOver

```
SELECT v.data, p.data  
from results r  
inner join vTable v on r.vId = v.vId   
inner join pTable p on r.pId = p.pId
```

I've tried the following:

```
var res = GetResults(some parameters)
            .Select(x => x.vId
            .Select(x => x.pID);

var dataset = session.QueryOver<vTable>()
                .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(v => v.vId).In(res)
                .Select(v => v.vId)
                .Select(v => v.data)
```

which works just fine to get data from vTable

however, when I add the 2nd table

```
var dataset = session.QueryOver<vTable>()
                .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(v => v.vId).In(res)
                .JoinQueryOver<pTable>(p => p.pId)
                .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(p => p.pId).In(res)
                .Select(v => v.vId)
                .Select(v => v.data)
                .Select(p => p.pId)
                .Select(p => p.data)
```

I get the error

```
Delegate 'System.Func<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<pTable>>' does not take 1 arguments
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.JoinQueryOver<pTable>(p => p.pId)
```

has to point to a mapped entity or collection not it an id, if you can't map it in the hbm. And also the JoinQueryOver will return pTables not vTables, you might want to use JoinAlias instead if you wan to retain the return type to be a list of vTables, but if all you want is that projection make sure you add aliases the QueryOver and JoinQueryOver calls